# Android Videoview, What I am missing that in my app?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I use the custom video view. but the problem is that I can hear the radio in my app but not showing anything, just black screen.

So I try to see the log and I got the error like

[image]

when i try to connect that site, I can get the .avi file. and It is working well.

but I don't know what i am missing that..

I attach my .java and .xml source.

.java source

```
public class ExerciseFragment
    extends Fragment {
private String uri = null;
public MyVideoView videoView;
private WebService ws = new WebService();
private CustomMediaController localCustomMediaController = null;

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration paramConfiguration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(paramConfiguration);
    if (paramConfiguration.orientation == 2) {
        this.videoView.isFull = true;
    }
    while (paramConfiguration.orientation != 1) {
        return;
    }
    this.videoView.isFull = false;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    paramBundle = getArguments();
    if (paramBundle != null) {
        this.uri = paramBundle.getString("uri");
    }
}

@Nullable
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater paramLayoutInflater, ViewGroup paramViewGroup, Bundle paramBundle) {
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
    View view = paramLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_correct_exercise, paramViewGroup, false);

    return view;
}

private VideoView mVideoView;

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (!User.logout) {
        this.ws.callSearchDialog(getActivity(), "조회중입니다.");
        this.videoView = ((MyVideoView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.videoView));
        localCustomMediaController = new CustomMediaController(getActivity());
    }
    try {
        this.videoView.setVideoPath(this.uri);
        this.videoView.bringToFront();
        this.videoView.setMediaController(localCustomMediaController);
        this.videoView.requestFocus();
        this.videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer paramAnonymousMediaPlayer) {
                ExerciseFragment.this.videoView.seekTo(2);
                ExerciseFragment.this.ws.removeSearchDialog();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception localException) {
        localException.printStackTrace();
        this.ws.removeSearchDialog();
    }
    ExerciseFragment.this.ws.removeSearchDialog();

}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

class CustomMediaController extends MediaController {
    ImageButton mCCBtn;
    Context mContext;

    public CustomMediaController(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    private View makeCCView() {
        this.mCCBtn = new ImageButton(this.mContext);
        this.mCCBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_fullscreen_24);
        this.mCCBtn.setBackgroundColor(0);
        this.mCCBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView) {
                paramAnonymousView = ExerciseFragment.this.videoView;
                if (ExerciseFragment.this.videoView.isFull) { // isFull =
                    ExerciseFragment.this.videoView.isFull = false;
                } else {
                    ExerciseFragment.this.videoView.isFull = true;
                }
                ExerciseFragment.this.videoView.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        return this.mCCBtn;
    }

    public void setAnchorView(View paramView) {
        super.setAnchorView(paramView);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        frameParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
        addView(makeCCView(), frameParams);
    }
}
```

and .xml source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_exercise"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<MyVideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

**updated**

this is MyVideoView.java

```
public class MyVideoView  extends VideoView
{
  public boolean isFull = false;

  public MyVideoView(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet)
  {
    super(paramContext, paramAttributeSet);
  }

  public void onMeasure(int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
  {
    if (this.isFull)
    {
      ((WindowManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
      setMeasuredDimension(paramInt1, paramInt2);
      return;
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(BaseActivity.displayWidth, BaseActivity.displayHeight/2);
  }
}
```

Could anyone help me please. Thanks

Comment: Did you tried with SurfaceView ?

Comment: @nihal_softy Nope, Do i  have to do that?? when I just use the videoview which is offered by Android, It is also not working.. so I am really confuse.

Comment: Yes I can understand... Actually Once I made this. If you wish then I can share you code. Your code looks fine

Comment: Are you using any third party VideoView ? I can see in XML that you had mentioned MyVideoView

Comment: @nihal_softy Nope, That was just all. there is no third party video view... and that MyVideoView is 'com.cheon.android.forgoodposture.Exercise.MyVideoView'.  and I updated MyVideoview class!

Comment: Okay, I am sharing one of sample with you. Test it and let me know

Comment: @nihal_softy Yes, Thanks! I tried your test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162785/discussion-between-adrian-and-nihal-softy).

Comment: Just one minute I am making shareable link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ps0a_dxCrHbjAPZ_kI_sqIqb-g1RhMI0

Comment: You can download project... Once get permission from mine side. so let em know.. Actually it was done using RecyclerView.. So sample I had attached you.let me now if you are satisfy with that :-)

Comment: I send the Access permission, please accpet it. then I will try it

Comment: I gave to you access it

Comment: Yep, I got it, I will back after tryingi t.

Comment: @nihal_softy Sir, your source is working very well. but I try to change the uri yours to mine, ~~/AppVideo.avi, It is also stil not showing but can hear the audio..

Comment: I changed uri in onBindViewHolder in VideoAdapter Class.

Comment: Okay Please give em your URL which you want to play

Comment: Sorry !! You mean you want to play video oflline means which you had stored in your phone memory ?

Comment: hm...nope.. I hope to get the uri from the web ...!!

Comment: Link which you had given me above its not working....

Comment: sir, I send the message in chat! lol

Comment: @nihal_softy Sir, maybe I could resolve it!  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html like this, Android don't support .avi. maybe that is the problem, So I will tell server manager convert .avi to .mp4. and maybe it is gonnabe success I think.

Comment: yes sure... You can play mp4 or FCCMPEG type file...

Comment: and in mp4 format you can use my code or else your own code will will work... but be sure if you want to customize your videoview then use my library which I had attached with my code. VideoVideo doesn't give you much more for customization..